# meteor one time initialization code on client side

Tags: javascript, meteor

Related: [Where to include Client-side Startup Code in Meteor React App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44611942/where-to-include-client-side-startup-code-in-meteor-react-app)

Similar issue here.

I want to do some imports from the server and also some initalization once on the client (the sooner the better).

Right now i have my code included in a template:

```
import { foo } from "../../imports/api/foo/foo.js";

Template.header.events({
    //init foo - should be called once and moved elsewehre
    ... 
    //use foo
});
```

But yeah ofc it's stupid because everytime the event is triggered the code gets called again.

On serverside i just used `Meteor.startup` for these things.

My Folder structure looks like this:

`/config
/models
/packages
/client/components //current code is here
/client/config
/client/lib
/imports/api
/imports/ui
/server/lib
/server/publications`

i heard that in previous meteor versions there were some folders for isomorphic code like a `/lib` folder but it seems like in meteor (1.3.5) the server and client code is split.

So where is a good place to do some initializations on the client side?

Comment: In addition to @Styx's answer, you should initialize in the `imports/api/foo/foo.js` file unless there's something special about your template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, it doesn't matter where do you place your startup code as long as you're calling it from your `client/main.js`.

I'd recommend to follow `Meteor`'s guide and proposed folder structure: [Example directory layout](https://guide.meteor.com/structure.html#example-app-structure), [Structuring imports](https://guide.meteor.com/structure.html#structuring-imports) and [Startup files](https://guide.meteor.com/structure.html#startup-files)

Comment: Does the main.js also apply if you don't have a main.html ?

Comment: Yes. It isn't related to `html` files at all.